# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID vedh51d2-retrieve-update has already been found in the view

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

I have reviewed my page for duplicate IDs and also made clean and build and I still get the same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID vrtrjrp2-retrieve-update has already been found in the view.  
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:846)
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:144)
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:133)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewStateManager.saveView(FlowViewStateManager.java:167)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Here's my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:pretty="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">    
    <h:head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:loadBundle basename="ValidationMessages" var="validation" />
        <br />
        <div style="height: 380px; left: 408px; margin: auto;absolute; width: 570px; -rave-layout: grid;background: url('resources/images/LoginImage.png') repeat scroll 0 0 transparent">
            <form action="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
                <c:if test="#{param.error != null}">
                    <div style="color: red;position: relative; left: 148px; top: 300px; width: 270px" >
                        Wrong Username/Password, try again.
                    </div>
                </c:if>
                <h:outputLabel for="j_username" id="outputLabel1" style="left: 48px; top: 120px; position: absolute" value=""/>
                <h:outputLabel for="j_password" id="outputLabel2" style="left: 48px; top: 168px; position: absolute" value=""/>
                <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" style="background:#cacaca;width: 237px; position: relative; left: 149px; top: 163px;" />
                <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true"  style="background:#cacaca; width: 237px; position: relative; right: 92px; top: 239px;"/>
                <h:commandButton id="loginBtn" style=" position: relative; top: 305px; right: 333px;" value="Login" image="/resources/images/Login.png"/>
                <h:commandButton id="resetBtn" style=" position: relative; top: 272px; left: 324px;" type="reset" value="reset" image="/resources/images/cancel.png"/>
                <h:outputText id="errorMessage" style="left:0px;top:300px;position:absolute"/>
                <h:message errorClass="errorMessage"  for="j_username" fatalClass="fatalMessage" id="messages1" infoClass="infoMessage" showSummary="false"
                    style="height: 43px; left: 24px; top: 288px; position: absolute; width: 523px;color:red;" warnClass="warnMessage"/>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </h:body>        
</html>
```

Comment: Does this occur when you open the login page or when you submit the form in the login page? If it occurs after submitting the form only, then the cause of the problem is according to the stacktrace not in the login page itself, but in the page where it is navigating to on succesful login. You should then look in there for the cause.

Comment: @BalusC, this occurs when opening login page.

Comment: Well, perhaps you're not running the code you think you're running. Clean/rebuild/redeploy.